# How to match data in two variables (list and dict) and print output combined

Tags: python, function, loops, variables, for-in-loop

I have two variables:

```
documents = [
    {'type': 'passport', 'number': '2207 876234', 'name': 'Smith'},
    {'type': 'invoice', 'number': '11-2', 'name': 'Obama'}, 
    {'type': 'insurance', 'number': '10006', 'name': 'Carpenter'}
]
directories = {'1': ['2207_876234', '11-2'], '2': ['10006'], '3': ['0']}
```

I have to write a code to have output in the format:
№: 2207 876234, type: passport, owner: Smith, shelf number: 1 №: 11-2, type: invoice, owner: Obama, shelf number: 1 №: 10006, type: insurance, owner: Carpenter, shelf number: 2

So I have written a code to start with

```
for k, v in directories.items():
    for info in documents:
        if v in [info]:
            print(k([info['number']]))
```

This seems not correct. Can somebody with experience give me an idea of how to combine two variables in one output format.

Comment: how about we create an intermediate object ? convert documents into an object of structure: { '2207 876234': {'type': 'passport', 'name': 'Smith' }}
during this conversion, you can add `_` in `2207 876234`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the prettiest but it works.

```py
documents = [
    {'type': 'passport', 'number': '2207 876234', 'name': 'Smith'},
    {'type': 'invoice', 'number': '11-2', 'name': 'Obama'}, 
    {'type': 'insurance', 'number': '10006', 'name': 'Carpenter'}
]
directories = {'1': ['2207_876234', '11-2'], '2': ['10006'], '3': ['0']}

entry_count = 0
out = []
for j,k in enumerate(directories):
    v = directories[k]
    for i,n in enumerate(directories[k]):
        if n == '0': 
            break
        data = documents[entry_count]
        out.append({ 'No': n, 'type': data['type'], 'owner': data['name'], 'shelf number': j + 1 })
        entry_count += 1

print(out)
```

Output:

```py
[{'no': '2207_876234', 'type': 'passport', 'owner': 'Smith', 'shelf number': 1},
 {'no': '11-2', 'type': 'invoice', 'owner': 'Obama', 'shelf number': 1},
 {'no': '10006', 'type': 'insurance', 'owner': 'Carpenter', 'shelf number': 2}]
```

---

After some thought on this it occurred to me that although your `documents` and `directories` have their `number` values in the same order in the example data, the above method would not hold up if their order changed.

However, the first value in `directories['1']` does not match the first number in `documents` - `'2207 876234' =/= '2207_876234'`

If we change the number in `documents` to match that in `directories`, the following code works and although slower, makes sure the number values match up regardless of the order the objects are in:

```py
documents = [
    {'type': 'passport', 'number': '2207_876234', 'name': 'Smith'},
    {'type': 'invoice', 'number': '11-2', 'name': 'Obama'}, 
    {'type': 'insurance', 'number': '10006', 'name': 'Carpenter'}
]
directories = {'1': ['2207_876234', '11-2'], '2': ['10006'], '3': ['0']}

out = []
for j,k in enumerate(directories):
    v = directories[k]
    for i,n in enumerate(directories[k]):
        data = next((d for d in documents if n == d['number']), None)
        if not data:
            continue
        out.append({ 'No': n, 'type': data['type'], 'owner': data['name'], 'shelf number': j + 1 })

print(out)
```

Output:

```py
[{'No': '2207_876234', 'type': 'passport', 'owner': 'Smith', 'shelf number': 1},
 {'No': '11-2', 'type': 'invoice', 'owner': 'Obama', 'shelf number': 1},
 {'No': '10006', 'type': 'insurance', 'owner': 'Carpenter', 'shelf number': 2}]
```

Note that the outputs are identical but the first method will not work if `documents` is re-ordered.

Comment: it's exactly what I ve been looking for

Comment: Could I ask, please, why have you put documents[entry_count] in a square brackets? I am at the early stages of coding, so a simple explanation for me would be very halpful

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as the solution. An array or list is a list of entries that can have any value. They are ordered starting at 0 for the first item, 1 for the second item, and so on. Typing `array_name[ index ]` gives you that entry in the array. In the example above, you cycle through the keys in `directories` ( '1', '2', and '3' ) and the values in each array `['2207...', '11-2'], ['10006']`, but you want them to apply to documents in-order: `index = 1, No = '11-2'` etc. To do them in-order, `entry_count` keeps count of which entry we are at and gets that value.

Comment: I've added an alternative method, and an explanation as to why it might be better, above. Note that the new method is slower but more reliable and may or may not be better for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

Match the values by this:

```
l=[]
for i in directories.values():
    for k in i:
        for y in documents:
            if y['number']==k:
                y['shelf number']=k
                l.append(y)
```

Change key names:

```
res=[]
for i in l:
    i['No']=i.pop('number')
    i['owner']=i.pop('name')
    res.append(i)

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{'type': 'invoice', 'shelf number': '11-2', 'No': '11-2', 'owner': 'Obama'}, {'type': 'insurance', 'shelf number': '10006', 'No': '10006', 'owner': 'Carpenter'}]
```